# Why are the review queues always empty?

Tags: support, review-queue

I've recently gained the privilege of accessing a few review queues, but they never have any questions in them. Is this due to lack of moderators/the time that moderators have? Or is somebody sitting on the queue reviewing questions as soon as they pop up?

Comment: ...except perhaps that "somebody" needs to be "somebodies" \*guilty look\*.

Comment: And of course Ser Rage is correct; there have been 60 reviews in the past 3 days, or an average of 20/day, which is less than 1/hr.

Comment: One thing I don't think mentioned yet is you don't have access to all the queues yet and those queues are the more multi user queues which stay in the queue for longer. When you get more rep and access to more of the queues you'll probably see that more review items become available to you.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Review queues aren't necessarily involved with (diamond) moderators at all: the whole review process can pass by without needing diamond moderator involvement. The review queues are all about normal community members doing moderation tasks like monitoring first posts and suggested edits, voting to close or reopen questions, etc.

For the last few years, SFF has had a small group of people who are *extremely* keen on reviewing, to the point where almost everything gets reviewed by one of a very few users. The makeup of this group has changed over time, but you can pretty much see who the current people are by looking at the stats of the [First Questions](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/review/first-questions/stats) and [First Answers](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/review/first-answers/stats) queues, which are brand-new, having been first created on 26 August this year during the network-wide review queue updates. Between them, these two queues have had a little over 1000 items so far (in the last two and a half months), with over 400 reviewed by one person and nearly 300 by another one person.

So basically your second option: somebod[ies] are sitting on the queue reviewing questions as soon as they pop up.

Comment: I think the next question has to be, is it necessarily *healthy* for the site that just two users are almost entirely monopolising both queues?

Comment: @Valorum: It takes five votes to close or reopen questions. Two users cannot actually decide whether a question is closed or open all by themselves.

Comment: @Kevin - Yes, but you and I both know that the first couple of actions can dramatically set the 'tone' for how a question is received by the community, especially if those actions include downvoting, delete-voting or posting a comment that's critical of the answer or the question.